# Synchronize two somewhat similar XML files by using the relative position of the elements

Tags: xml, xslt, synchronization, xslt-2.0

*Story:
I have 2 files. 1 has incorrect ID's and different language. I want to copy name and description from that file to another file, but leave everything else untouched.*

I have 2 really long xml files that look something like this:

```
<item>
     <itemtype id="1" classname="chair">
         <name>Chair</name>
         <description>Wooden chair</description>
     </itemtype>
</item>
```

So I want to change that name and description, to match the info in another file. (Also possibly id)
Is there a program to do this?
Or a php code that would do it?

File 1:

```
    <item>
     <itemtype id="1" classname="chair">
         <name>Chair</name>
         <description>Wooden chair</description>
     </itemtype>
</item>
```

300 times this same, but with different id, name and description.

File 2:

```
    <item>
     <itemtype id="24" classname="chair">
         <name>Seat</name>
         <description>White wooden seat</description>
     </itemtype>
</item>
```

300 times the same, but with random id, name and description.

I want to use file 2, but I can't because the "id" is wrong. That's why I want to use file 1, and change the name and description to match the info in file 2.

Comment: What platform are you using?  Operating system/programming language(s) available/etc. I know you mentioned PHP but is that all you have available?

Comment: Using Windows (or ubuntu). I have PHP, HTML and Visual Basic knowledge, and I can do something in C#

Comment: You probably want to use an XSLT processor that supports XSLT 2.0.  If you retag the question with XSLT you'll get some good answers (I'm not as familar with 2.0, but I do know that it makes it easier to merge files).

Comment: Please show as all types of input documents, what the merged output would look like in that specific case, and explain all the peculiarities: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: "*300 times this same*" Do you mean you have 300 pairs of files? Are you able to identify the pairs?

Comment: I have 300 "item":s in one xml file, that have unique "id". Also classname, name and description is different usually.

Comment: I've adjusted your title to reflect what I think your intend was. Feel free to update your question if my assumptions weren't correct, but if so, make sure to explain exactly how otherwise an item from file 1 is found in file 2 if all shown properties are unequal.

Answer (score 0):

*This is an old question, you've probably resolved your issue by now, but it is still open and not deleted, so let me give it a try.*

You say:

> I want to use file 2, but I can't because the "id" is wrong. That's why I want to use file 1, and change the name and description to match the info in file 2.

and from comments:

> I have 300 "item":s in one xml file, that have unique "id". Also classname, name and description is different usually

So, that means that the four fields we have, id, classname, name and description are different and cannot be used to lookup an item from file 1 in file 2. The only thing that seems to match in your description is the number of items in both files

Since there **must** be some way to logically match an item from file 1 with file 2, the only thing remaining is the item's relative position. So, for the following solution with XSLT, I am going to assume the following requirements:

1. Take item number X from file 1, starting with the first
2. Create a shallow copy
3. Use the `@id` from file 1
4. Find the item in the same position X in file 2
5. Use the classname, name and description from file 2
6. If not the last record, go to the next record X + 1 and begin with step 1 again.

In XSLT this is quite straightforward:

```
<xsl:param name="doc1" select="document('doc1.xml')" />
<xsl:param name="doc2" select="document('doc2.xml')" />

<xsl:template name="main">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$doc1/*" />
</xsl:template>

<!-- identity transform, used by $doc1 and (parts of) $doc2 -->
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="itemtype">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@id" />
        <xsl:attribute name="classname" 
            select="$doc2/item/itemtype[$pos]/@classname" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$doc2/item/itemtype[$pos]/*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The code above is XSLT 1.0 compatible, but it will also work with XSLT 2.0. You should call it by initiating the stylesheet by named template "main", and set the two parameters to whatever the locations of your XML files are.

It copies as much as it can from file 1, but copies the `@classname` and any elements under `<itemtype>` from file 2.

If your requirements are more complex than this, you can of course amend the above boilerplate code. I did not test the code (just wrote it by hand), but I believe it should work.